# How does the donation cooldown work?

Tags: clash-royale

I recently got a 'donation cooldown' notification, preventing me from donating cards further:

[image: screenshot of notification described above]

What triggers this? How does the donation cooldown work? Is there a specific time when the daily donation limit resets? When I got the donation cooldown notification, it didn't start from 24 hours, but from around 35 minutes.

Comment: I just joined this part of stack exchange because the answer by @Isuka doesn't seem to address the question. Note that I do not have the answer but I can say that the difference between the Daily donation limit and the donation cool down is completely different. Here's example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FyuuW.png As you can see, the Donation cooldown is faster than the the reset of the daily donations. In case anybody's wondering why this isn't a comment, I don't know how to post pictures in a comment. I'll experiment further.

Answer (score 4):

The donation system now works this way:

Every 7 hours, the members of a clan can ask for cards (common and rare during the week, epic during Sunday). Depending on your arena level, the number of cards you can give/receive is modified. If you donated too many cards during this 7 hour period, you will then have the cool down, preventing you from asking/giving further cards.

The number of cards you can ask/give for each arena is the following:

**Goblin Stadium**

- Donating: 1 common card or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 10 common cards or 1 rare card.

**Bone Pit**

- Donating: 2 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 10 common cards or 1 rare card.

**Barbarian Bowl**

- Donating: 2 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 10 common cards or 1 rare card.

**P.E.K.K.A's Playhouse**

- Donating: 4 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 20 common cards or 2 rare cards.

**Spell Valley**

- Donating: 4 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 20 common cards or 2 rare cards.

**Builder's Workshop**

- Donating: 4 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 20 common cards or 2 rare cards.

**Royal Arena**

- Donating: 6 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 30 common cards or 3 rare cards.

**Frozen Peak**

- Donating: 6 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 30 common cards or 3 rare cards.

**Jungle Arena**

- Donating: 6 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 30 common cards or 4 rare cards.

**Hog Mountain**

- Donating: 8 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 40 common cards or 4 rare cards.

**Legendary Arena**

- Donating: 8 common cards or 1 rare card.
- Asking: 40 common cards or 1 rare cards.

Comment: Is there a specific time when the daily donation limit resets? Because when I got the donation cooldown notification, it didn't start from 24 hrs, but from around 35 minutes.

Comment: I'm looking for that information in-game. I will edit my answer as soon as I figure that point.

Comment: Was it also 35minutes away from the in-game daily chest (can't remember the name, the one you need 10 crowns for)

Comment: Try to compare it with the market refresh timer. It's possible they are using their 00:00 wherever they are based. SO the market and the donation limit would refresh at 00:00 on the next day where they are.

Comment: @Mathias711 I didn't notice if it was the same time as the crown chest.

Comment: I'm not sure it is related to the Crown Chest, as the daily time for this one is different for each player. Though I would go for the midnight option.

Comment: I got a donation cooldown notice again. Currently 2h 14min while card shop says 7h 3min.

Comment: Looking at the time you gave this information and the cooldown, and the time you posted the question and the corresponding cooldown, it looks like it is something around 11:20 AM UTC+1 for you or something like that.

Comment: Based on my experience - it is a 24 hour cool down that seems locked to the first time you ever donated cards.  I speculate that this could reset at some point if you ever went more than 2 days without donating, but I'm playing the game way too much to test that atm.  It may just be locked to that time though.  This should also mean that you can end up being able to donate 120 cards in one 24 hour period, borrowing from the cooldown of the previous day.

Comment: Either this answer is outdated, or I'm missing something.  It seems the donation limit is different for each arena now? I don't play the game so I don't know exactly how it works - but could you update this if needed?

Comment: @TimmyJim It's totally right. The answer was updated.